# Moving nodes in a tree in EXTJS 4

Tags: extjs, tree, extjs4

Am working on moving nodes in a tree, and as they are moved, their ID's are updated in the database through C# in the back-end. Till now, i have managed to update the position of the node that is being moved, but after its moved, the position of the other nodes in the tree should also get updated. Could anyone tell me how to proceed with this?

```
itemmove : {
fn : function(v, oldParent, newParent, index, eOpts) {
var nodeID = v.data.id;
var oldParent = oldParent.data.id;
var newParent = newParent.data.id;
var index = index;
var level = v.data.level;
movenode(nodeID, oldParent, newParent, index, level);
}
}


function movenode(nodeID, oldParent, newParent, index, level) {
Ext.Ajax.request({
    url : 'data/pages.aspx',
    params : {
        UserID : USER.UserID,
        mode : 'MOVENODE',
        currentNode : nodeID,
        oldParentNode : oldParent,
        newParentNode : newParent,
        index : index,
        level : level,
        ProjDB : projDB
    },
    success : function() {
        loadTREEst();
        genMessage(LANG.Suc, LANG.SaveOK, 'tick', false);

    },
    failure : function() {
        genMessage(LANG.Warn, LANG.GenWarn, 'warn', false);
    }
});
}
```

So, i send the parameters to SQl, and then update the index of the node that has been moved.

For example, if i move a node from position 8 to 1, the index of the 8th node changes to 1 in the database, but the index of the first node remains at 1. And because of this, the tree also doesnt get updated. i want all the other nodes in the tree to get updated as well. So, in this case, the node in index 1 will become index 2, the node in index 2 will become index 3, and so on. Can anyone explain me how to do this.

Is there any other method other than autosync or sync to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of ExtJS are you using? Because in 4.1 it is done automatically by the framework given your model is defined correctly.

Comment: EXTJS 4.1 Do you mean to say about AutoSync, if so i tried doing that, the tree is getting updated, but not the database.

Comment: I reckon you mean 4.0.7? If so, this part wasn't working properly in that version, but AutoSync does work with 4.1, I've been using it with direct and the update records sent are correct and do handle reordering and moving on a treepanel perfectly well. I'll look for the manual reordering code I had for 4.0.7 and will post it shortly.

Comment: Thank you for that:) How about store.sync(); Does this work? I read this method in some post, but this too doesnt work.

Comment: Let me know if you wish to see how sync works and I'll post some code. But as I said, it doesn't work correctly with 4.0.7;

Comment: Yup, i would surely like to know how sync works:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some sample code that works with 4.1:

```
Ext.define('BS.model.ItemCategory', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'name'     , type: 'string'},
        {name: 'iconCls'  , type: 'string', defaultValue: 'treenode-no-icon'},
        {name: 'leaf'     , type: 'boolean', defaultValue: false},
        {name: 'expanded' , type: 'boolean', defaultValue: true, persist: false},
        {name: 'index'     , type: 'int'},        
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'direct',

        api: {
            create: ItemCategories.Create,
            read: ItemCategories.Read,
            update: ItemCategories.Update,
            destroy: ItemCategories.Delete,
        },
    }, 
});
```

You won't be having a direct proxy as your server isn't php, but just put the corresponding server scripts (see [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Server-cfg-api)).

Then my store:

```
Ext.define('BS.store.ItemCategories', {

    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',    
    model: 'BS.model.ItemCategory',

    autoSync: true,

    root: {
        text: 'Root',
        id: 'NULL',
        expanded: true
    },

    clearOnLoad: true,
});
```

And the view:

```
Ext.define('BS.view.admin.pages.item-categories.ItemCategories' ,
{
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias : 'widget.item-categories-tree',

    store: 'ItemCategories',

    displayField: 'name',

    rootVisible: false,
    useArrows: true,
    multiSelect: false,
    singleExpand: false,    
    allowDeselect: true,

    plugins: {
        ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',                    
    },          
});
```

That's pretty much it! When you move a node you'll see ExtJS sends an update request to the server with an array of all the nodes whose index (sort) has changed.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Izhaki, but for some reason its not working in 4.1. Am trying to figure out why, will keep posted

Comment: But EXTJS 4.1 has the autoSync as a bug. Refer this link: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?200852-TreeStore-autosync-not-firing-when-nodes-reordered-within-same-parent.

Comment: It works for me. Looking at the bug reports it seem they forgot to define index in their model.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I had for 4.0.7, to my memory it solved this problem.

```
// This happens after drag and drop
onItemMove: function(aNode, aOldParent, aNewParent, aIndex, aOptions)
{

    // Update the indeces of all the parent children (not just the one that moved)
    for ( i = 0; i < aNewParent.childNodes.length; i++ )
    {
        aNewParent.childNodes[i].data.sort = i;
        aNewParent.childNodes[i].setDirty();
    }

    this.mStore.sync();
},
```

Notice that you won't have mStore.sync() as you are sending your own request to the server, which only involves one record. By setting child nodes as dirty, sync sends more than one record to the server's update call (in my case, I'm using autosync and direct).

You should consider what happens when the user moves a node from a parent node to the parent's sibling - the index (sort) of some nodes in both the old and new parent will change. So you might end up with 6 records that need updating on the server.

All I'm saying is that given 4.1 already handles node moving correctly, you might be better off upgrading to 4.1 and take advantage of the native support for this than coding it yourself. If you stick to 4.0.7, just remember to consider that a moving a node could require the updating of many nodes.

Comment: Cool. Thank you so much for that. So, could you also explain me how to do this in EXTJS 4.1? How does it handle it automatically?